# IP Address Confusion

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp

I am trying to configure my Raspbeery PI 3b running on Ubutu MATE 16.04 to be a Hotspot and so all equipment that access to this network would use the IP in the range of 192.168.42.10-20

I am using the dnsmasq and I have edited the `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` to take the  following

1. ```
   dhcp-range=192.168.42.10,192.168.42.20,12h
   ```
2. Uncomment `no-resolv`

and I have set for the `/etc/sysctl.conf`

1. Uncomment `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

The rest of the configuration is pretty much the same as unaltered. When I reboot the system, the IP address is 10.42.0.1 and the subsequent machine which join the network is along the IP of 10.42.0.x

Diagnostics:

I tried to see the `/etc/network/interfaces`, it read

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

    # The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```